# displayng number pyramid in O(n) execution

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

How do we print the following with `O(n)` execution
may be using a single for loop?

```
1
2 3
4 5 n
```

up to `n` rows
all I can do is using nested for loops

Comment: nested for loop doesn't mean it's not `O(n)`!

Comment: init: prev <- 0 , and in loop: if (i == prev + 1) { prev++; print newline; } Note that is does not make it any better performance, in terms of big O notations.

Answer (score 1):

Nested for loop doesn't necessarily mean it's not `O(n)` any more. If what's inside the nested loop gets executed `O(n)` times, then the nested loop is perfectly fine:

```
cur_num <- 1
cur_step <- 1
while cur_num <= n
    for i <- 1 to cur_step
        print cur_num++
    cur_step++
    print '\n'
```

With a single for loop, it's doable, but slightly less pleasant

```
cur_num <- 1
cur_step <- 1
cur_step_consumed <- 0
for i <- 1 to n
    print cur_num++
    cur_step_consumed++
    if cur_step_consumed == cur_step
         cur_step_consumed <- 0
         cur_step++
         print '\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++:

```
size_t amount = 1;
size_t count = 0;
for(size_t i=1;i<=n;++i){
   cout << i << " ";
   ++count;
   if (count == amount){
      cout << endl;
      count = 0;
      ++amount;
   }
}
```

output for n = 29:

```
1
2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20 21
22 23 24 25 26 27 28
29
```

The idea is to track the number of elements to print in the current row, and track the number of elements printed in the current row. When the number of elements we've printed for the current row is the same as the total number of elements to print for that row, reset the count and increment the number of elements to print for the next row. You can mess with the formatting to get prettier output, but this is the gist of how it can be done in O(n) time and O(1) space.